# Product of symmetric matrices $AB^2A$

Tags: linear-algebra

If the $n$ x $n$ matrices $A$ and $ B$ are symmetric and $B$ is invertible, is the product of $ AB^2A$ symmetric as well?

I understand that if a matrix product commutes $AB = BA$, which I believe to mean $(AB)^T = B^TA^T = BA$ that their product will be symmetric. But I'm not sure how to apply this to the problem.

Would this be on the right track:
since we know $A^T=A$ and $(B^2)^T=B^2$
then we have $(AB^2A)^T=A^T(B^2)^TA^T=A(B^T\cdot B^T)A=A(B\cdot B)A=AB^2A$.
Thus the matrix product $AB^2A$ commutes.
Does this work?

Comment: I think instead of $AB^2B$ you want $AB^2A$ (in which case your proof will work)

Comment: Are you asking about $AB^2B$ or $AB^2A$? Your subject says  $AB^2B$

Comment: @TokenToucan Thank you, I didn't see my mistake.

Comment: @Lem.ma Thanks as well

Comment: I think $B$ invertible is not needed.